# Using mockito, how do I match a field of a field?

Tags: mocking, arguments, mockito

I'm using mockito 1.9.5.  I want to setup a mock call something like

```
            Mockito.doReturn(mockSearchData)
                    .when(myMock)
                    .searchOrganizations(id, 
                                 null,
                                 detailedSearchCriteria, 
                                 null);
```

only that I want to specify that I want to setup the mock when the "id" field of the "detailedSearchCriteria" object is equal to the value of "ZZ."  The "detailedSearchCriteria" doesn't have an equals method and I don't control the code in order to create one.  Is there any way to do this with mockito and if not, what is another framework and how could this be done there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own `ArgumentMatcher`, that checks whether the `detailedSearchCriteria` matches what you need.  Check out the Mockito documentation on custom argument matchers at http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html